# Exception java.lang.ClassCastException al serializar

Tags: excepciones, serializacion

Tengo el siguiente código de una clase hotel que almacena en un ArrayList diferentes objetos de tipo hotel:

La clase hotel implementa Serializable y está compuesta de los atributos nombre, descripción, ciudad y precio

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcion;
    boolean salir = false;
    ArrayList<hotel> hoteles = new ArrayList<hotel>();
    ArrayList<hotel> hoteles_recuperado = new ArrayList<hotel>();
    ArrayList<hotel> hotel_encontrado = new ArrayList<hotel>();
    String fichero = "C:\\Users\\Jomar\\Desktop\\nombre.txt";

    do {
        System.out.println("\n---------------- Menú ----------------");
        System.out.println("1.- Añadir hotel");
        System.out.println("2.- Modificar hotel");
        System.out.println("3.- Borrar hotel");
        System.out.println("4.- Listar hoteles");
        System.out.println("0.- Salir");

        try {
            System.out.println("Introduzca opción");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
            hotel hotel1 = new hotel("Ayre Hotel Gran via", "Buenas vistas", "Barcelona", 60);
                hotel hotel2 = new hotel("Hotel Marbella", "Exclusivo", "Marbella", 89);
                hotel hotel3 = new hotel("Hotel La Ermita", "Barato", "Brunete", 55);
                hotel hotel4 = new hotel("Hotel Rey Pelayo", "Buena zona", "Gijón", 56);
                hoteles.add(hotel1);
                hoteles.add(hotel2);
                hoteles.add(hotel3);
                hoteles.add(hotel4);

                // Mostrar el ArrayList
                System.out.println("--- Hoteles añadidos ---");
                for (hotel hotel : hoteles) {
                    System.out.println(hotel);
                }
                // Añadimos los hoteles al fichero
                try {
                    // Escribimos la informacion
                    // OUTPUT ECRIBIR
                    ObjectOutputStream escribe = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero));
                    escribe.writeObject(hoteles);
                    escribe.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                    System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("--- Modificar hotel ---");
                System.out.println("Que hotel desea modificar");
                String modifica = sc.nextLine();
                boolean encontrado = false;
                try {
                    ObjectInputStream lee = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fichero));
                    
                    hoteles = (ArrayList<hotel>) lee.readObject();
                    lee.close();

                    for (hotel hotel : hoteles) {
                        if (hotel.getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(modifica)) {
                            System.out.println(hotel);
                            encontrado = true;
                            // Modificar el precio del hotel
                            System.out.println("Escriba el nuevo precio");
                            int new_pre = sc.nextInt();
                            
                            ObjectOutputStream escribe = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero));
                            hotel.setPrecio_noche(new_pre);                                 escribe.writeObject(hotel);
                            escribe.close();
                        }
                    }
                    // Si no encuentra el hotel, fuera del bucle mostramos el mensaje de no
                    // encontrado
                    if (encontrado == false) {
                        System.out.println("El hotel no se ha encontrado");
                    }
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error e");
                }
                
                break;
                
            case 4:
                
                try {
                    ObjectInputStream lee1 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fichero));
                

                        hoteles = (ArrayList) lee1.readObject();
                        System.out.println(hoteles);

                    
                    lee1.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                    }
                break;
```

Lo que me ocurre es que después de hacer una modificación de un hotel (case 2), cuando voy a listarlos (case 4) me aparece la Exception Exception java.lang.ClassCastException diciendo que no puede ser casteado a ArrayList cuando en el case 2 sí que me deja hacerlo perfectamente.

He probado también usando instanceof y tampoco lista los hoteles.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Felicidades por solucionar tu problema tú mismo; quiero hacer dos apuntes: 1) Pon el tag del lenguaje que usas (en este caso, 'java') al hacer una pregunta, 2) Es perfectamente válido que respondas a tu propia pregunta, y puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada. O puedes borrar la pregunta. En general, yo recomendaría el criterio de si piensas que es lo suficientemente general como para que pueda ayudar a otra gente con tu mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado:

El problema es que en el case 2 estaba añadiendo objetos al fichero y no el arrayList en su totalidad.

Entonces cuando en el case 4 intentaba castear a ArrayList, después de haber añadido objetos, me decía que no podía hacer el casting.